# What is faster: Checking for null pointer or calling empty function?

Tags: c++

I'm building a system where I'll have to call multiple times some commands depending on user input, eg

```
void handle(int MouseInput)
{
    switch(MouseInput)
    {
    case Move:  
        ActionMove->execute(); 
        // ...
    case BtnUp: 
        ActionBtnUp->execute(); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Yet since the system is parametrizable, not always do I have eg an `actionMove` command object (sometimes I do nothing on Move).

What's faster :

- Implementing the null object pattern, ie having an object with an `execute` function like so

  ```
  execute() {}
  ```
- Or checking for null pointers every time :

  ```
  if (ActionBtnUp) ActionBtnUp->execute();
  ```

What I'm asking is what's of greater overhead, the cost to jump to a function that does nothing (maybe it's easy for the compiler to optimize this away) or to check for a null pointer every time ?

Note I can only test small scale for now and can't see any differences. If that's the case I'd like to know.

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me. Go with whatever makes your code clearer and cleaner, and optimize if you find a performance issue here.

Comment: How about you encapsulate the logic, go with the simpler one for now, build until you have a larger scale, then profile both solutions?

Comment: I'd make a test program, with some sort of dynamically generated input that simulates both methods, turn on the optimizations you intend to use, then profile it.

Comment: If you have a bigger system and it turns out to be a problem making the switch shouldn't be too difficult. That being said  prematurely trading off understandability for an optimization that may not pay off will cost you right now. A null object will make things easier as there's always one thing to do, execute,  rather that two, check and then maybe execute. a null check is probably faster, the question is does that cost matter.

Comment: I don't see how you are going to implement the 'null object' whilst `ActionMove` is a pointer , maybe you could include a bit more detail.

Comment: The difference will be a few nanoseconds, and this is for handling user input, so it will be absolutely unsignificant (no need to optimize here).

Comment: In order for `ActionBtnUp` to be able to point to something that might have an empty `execute()` or might point to something that might really do something useful you would need it to point to a base class and make `execute()` virtual. For the compiler to be able to optimize that call away it would have to be able to statically prove which derived type the pointer points to. And if it can do that it can probably tell when the pointer is null and remove the check. So neither is going to be more optimisable. (Oh, I see MattMcNabb just made the same point two comments above).

Comment: There are two valid answers to questions like these: the first one, is "measure and find out"; the second one is "unless you have concrete requirements and measurements for efficiency, the faster one, is the one that is faster to implement, maintain and test".

Comment: @JonathanWakely `execute` is indeed virtual (typical Command pattern implementation). The question shows the code being called when the mouse moves ie **all the time**; so I went for '_Belated pessimization is the leaf of no good_' . When popular optimization tips include things like Alexandrescu's '_when comparing against a constant, better compare against zero_' I don't see how this question is too much of a nitpick.

Comment: @BrunoLevy Thanks for the tip. Kudos for geogram once again

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou, If the function is already virtual then my next consideration would be how often the pointer is null. If it points to a real object most of the time then optimising for the uncommon case where it's null is foolish, maybe you should be more concerned that when it isn't null you do a check _and_ a function call, instead of worrying about whether the check or the function call is faster in the rare cases. You haven't provided any clue about relative frequency, so there's no way for us to know "which is faster" overall (and see the first comment again)...

Comment: ... if you must micro-optimise, make sure you do it for the common case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `ActionBtnUp` to be able to point to something that might have an empty `execute()` or might point to something that might really do something useful you would need it to point to a base class and make `execute()` virtual.

For the compiler to be able to optimize that call away it would have to be able to statically prove which derived type the pointer points to. And if it can do that it can probably tell when the pointer is null and remove the check. So it's likely that neither is going to be easier for the compiler to optimize.

If the `execute()` function is not already virtual then changing it to be virtual and adding a new class type just to be able to avoid a null-pointer check is probably a bad idea. You should use virtual functions when they make sense for variation in behaviour, not just to micro-optimise null pointer checks.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, unless you notice a performance issue or you are doing this a few thousand times every few seconds, it probably does not have much effect on performance. Do what makes the most sense to you, and what is most readable and cleaner to implement. The time saved during maintenance by doing this might be greater than the total sum of time your program spends doing an extra comparison.

Comment: s/few thousand times/a million times/

Comment: The function is clearly triggered whenever the mouse is moved. Seems pretty performance-critical to me....

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit But just a comparison? there is more to be worried about in the functions that this calls than how it decides what to do.

Comment: @Snappawapa: I didn't claim otherwise. Doesn't mean you can just ignore it. 1+5 is still greater than 5.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Very true, but I did not mean to ignore it, but recognize the minimality of the issue, address it if need be, and otherwise do what is best for clean and readable code

Comment: @Snappawapa: Sure. Just remember that this function _is_ critical and deserves special care and attention. There is little worse than your mouse cursor slowing down because some programmer wrote inefficient code when they had an easyish design choice to make.

Answer (score 3):

Optimize for code understandability first. Only ever optimize for execution speed after you know you have a problem. In my experience, well structured code, which is loosely coupled with good locality of reference, tends to also be very fast code. If nothing else, it's easier for the compiler to optimize.

In terms of understandability, the null object pattern may be better-- you test for null in only one place. Testing for null before every dereference seems to me to violate "Don't Repeat Yourself".

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense for your `ActionMove` to be null ? If the answer is yes, I believe you should test for null pointer. If it shouldn't be null, just use a reference and do not test for null pointer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern (although that makes more sense in OO languages where all method calls do dynamic dispatch anyway)